# How to send beacon with viens

Tags: omnet++, veins

I know How to send a message for car a to car b or rsu. but I need to send beacons. what is different between sending a message and sending beacons. I cant see any sendBeacon(). How should I send one?

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you are trying to achieve? I am confused by you saying you want to send a beacon, while at the same time asking what that is...

Comment: I am saying How can I send a beacon? Is there any function or method for this task or should I make one. I never seen any code sending beacon message

Comment: Beacons are sent by default. If you want to modify their content, override the populateWSM method; refer to the source code for the details: https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, a beacon is simply a repeated broadcast message that carries some information of general interest in the vicinity of the sender. You can achieve this in Veins by having your application call its `sendDown` method every once in a while.

You can find some example code that does this in https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L242