# Sending a "beacon hello"

Tags: omnet++, veins

A vehicle entering the simulation must send a "Hello beacon" to form a cluster.

If there is already a vehicle, it will respond with another "Hello beacon".

How can this be done in the veins?

I saw this previous post, but I don't know if my case is the same:

[How to send beacon with viens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961795/how-to-send-beacon-with-vi)

The post has been edited to add the comment image below:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e76XL.png)

Comment: In what way is your case different?

Comment: I thought my case would be different because HELLO Beacon would only have the vehicle ID, position and type. I created a ClusterHelloBeacon.msg message by extending WaveShortMessage. From this message the files ClusterHelloBeacon_m.h and ClusterHelloBeacon_m.cc were created. However when implementing the use of the message the error of the attached figure is displayed.

Comment: The error was because this line " `wsm->setWsmData(mobility->getRoadId().c_str());` " was missing. But I don't know what this line does.